# Elegant way of representing branches checking whether a key is present in a dict

Tags: python

In a few projects of mine, when I want to perform some action depending on whether a key is in dictionary, I use a rather ugly and straightforward method of just branching with if so I end up with quite a few of things like (in this example I know that if `someDict` contains the key, `someDict2` does, too.

```
if someKey in someDict:
    someDict[someKey] += x
    someDict2[someKey] += y
else:
    someDict[someKey] = x
    someDict2[someKey] = y
```

And I was just wondering, is there a more elegant way of doing it? `setdefault()` doesn't seem to be an answer here cause in case of the key being present, I want to add some value not being dependent on what is currently stored.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `collections.defaultdict()` really.

Comment: It appears that the asker wants the action on someDict2 dependant on someDict, so `defaultdict` wouldn't work. Interesting question to pose, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are numeric, you could use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default value of zero:

```
someDict[someKey] = someDict.get(someKey, 0) + x
someDict2[someKey] = someDict2.get(someKey, 0) + y
```

---

If `x` is known at the time `someDict` is created, then you could use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
someDict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: x)
someDict[someKey] += x
```

(and similarly fo `someDict2`.)

Comment: He wants what he does with someDict to affect someDict2, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @AaronHall: I don't understand what you are getting at. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AaronHall: if the code always assigns to the same key in both `someDict` *and* `someDict2` it hardly matters here.

Comment: The logic is to check `if someKey in someDict`, which then affects both operations. There is no better way than what he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

For this logic:

```
if someKey in someDict:
    someDict[someKey] += x
    someDict2[someKey] += y
else:
    someDict[someKey] = x
    someDict2[someKey] = y # even if somekey was already in y
```

> **is there a more elegant way of doing it?**

No, there is no more efficient or Pythonic way of performing these precise semantics. You want a memory of the check for `someDict`, which will affect what you do with both dicts. This is impossible to further simplify.

Comment: There usually *is* a more elegant way of doing it, but it depends on the type of values stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the dict class with a dedicated method to handle the if/then

```
class my_dict(dict):
    def add(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            self[key] += value
        else:
            self[key] = value

someDict = my_dict()
someDict2 = my_dict()

someDict.add('a', 3)  # {'a': 3}
someDict2.add('a', 4) # {'a': 4}
someDict.add('a', 2)  # {'a': 5}
someDict2.add('a', 2) # {'a': 6}
someDict.add('b', 10)  # {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
someDict2.add('b', 20) # {'a': 6, 'b': 20}
```